# The etymology of "astrigmentum"

Tags: etymology, medieval-latin

As I understand from several sources ([e.g](https://books.google.com/books?id=JKO-u2OOv-IC&pg=PA60&lpg=PA60&dq=astrigmentum&source=bl&ots=jHvr7_CzDd&sig=ACfU3U3disHXBu41FzfkQ7f7xPU2A8NG6g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwil5Pz5yJPsAhUaURUIHb2ZDLcQ6AEwAnoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=astrigmentum&f=false)) it's meaning is kind of lace/straps. Apparently its a of a medieval origin (encountered that word in Luis Vives 16h century). But I struggle to see how this word came into being: a lone-word? or a new compound word based on stem (like "astrigmen" or so)I was unable to locate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Astrigmentum* is formed from the verb *astringere* (= prefix *ad* + *stringere*), 'to tie up tightly,' and the suffix *mentum*. In general, this suffix forms 'nouns denoting *acts*, or *means* and *results* of acts' (Allen & Greenough, *New Latin grammar* §239). Here it denotes 'means' specifically and is added to a de-nasalized form of the present/imperfective verb stem (*astring* > *astrig*). Therefore, the word *astrigmentum* is literally 'a means of tying up.'

The word *fragmentum* has a similar derivation from a de-nasalized verb stem (of the verb *frangere*, 'to break') + *mentum*. However, the suffix denotes 'results' instead of 'means,' so that a *fragmentum* is literally 'the result of breaking'.

Incidentally, *strigmentum*, which is mentioned in the other answer, is from the unprefixed root verb of *astringere*, also de-nasalized. In this case, though, the verb is used with the meaning 'to strip,' 'to shave,' or 'to skim the surface of.' Here too, as for *fragmentum*, the suffix denotes 'results.'

Answer (score 3):

Looks like one possible etymology means "[material] thoroughly scraped off." Or perhaps "scraped away."

*a + strigmentum*

<s>*a* = not (privative alpha)</s>

*a* = "away from;" "completely, thoroughly;" indicates absence

*strigmentum, i,* n.

> I. In gen., **that which is scratched or scraped off**, **a scraping**
> (post-Aug.), Plin. 20, 3, 8, § 17.— II. In participle, **filth or dirt
> scraped off**, Cels. 2, 6 med.; 5, 2, 4; Plin. 9, 51, 74, § 160; 28,
> 4, 13, § 51; Val. Max. 9, 14, ext. 2 al.

From the Lewis and Short lexicon, via Perseus Word Study Tool

Comment: Good catch; the PIE to Latin equivalent is in-. Answer edited.